# How to label each variables being clustered with kmeans in r

Tags: r, label, k-means

The question that follows refers to this comment @ialm "I also added an answer to plot the actual labels, if you really want to! – ialm Jul 9 '13 at 21:43" posted here: [How to label k-means clusters in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17557984/how-to-label-k-means-clusters-in-r/42725946#42725946)

Thank you very much for your help, would you be so kind as to suggest me how to add in the general code the command to plot the actual labels for each variable being clustered? Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want to know which cluster each data point belongs to?

Comment: I would like each point to have a label with the name of the variable (or of the observation) it represents. In the  example mentioned (https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Data_Mining_Algorithms_In_R/Clustering/K-Means) the labels I am looking for would be the names of the countries. Thank you!